# Elasticsearch throwing resource_already_exists_exception

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm mapping index **rides_order_266** .
elastic throwing exception **resource_already_exists_exception**. after reading the exception message. It looks like index **rides_order_266** already exists but if this is the case then elastic search throw exception **index_already_exists_exception**. I am getting confused that I am right or wrong. can some explain the exception message?

Elasticsearch version: 6.4.2

```
[resource_already_exists_exception] index [rides_order_266/aGTcXrUrTAOV12qxEHl9tQ] already exists, with { index_uuid=\"aGTcXrUrTAOV12qxEHl9tQ\" & index=\"rides_order_266\" }","path":"/rides_order_266","query":{},"body":"{\"settings\":{\"index\":{\"mapping.total_fields.limit\":70000,\"number_of_shards\":1,\"number_of_replicas\":0,\"refresh_interval\":\"1s\"}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`resource_already_exists_exception` is the new name of this error. It used to be `index_already_exists_exception` and has been renamed in version 6.0 as you can see in [PR #21494](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/21494).

That change was made to prevent having one different exception for each different resource type (index, alias, etc).

So, what you get is perfectly OK, given the `rides_order_266` index already exists.